# Where do I put CRUD operations in a reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs, crud, idioms

The web is full of people telling me I'm doing react wrong. I'm sure they're right, since I've just started. A commonly referenced truism is that react is just the view layer. That's wonderful, but it leaves me wondering simply **where do I put my other stuff?**

I have a pretty straight-forward set of components which together show a list of nested data types and allow some editing, creation, and removal of the things. The components which consume the data have it passed in through props down the hierarchy from a parent that fetches the data. Should those read operations go somewhere else if it's "just the view layer"

**What's the best practice for this, the idiomatic way, the react way?** Should my delete operation be included with my delete button component? next to the read operation? somewhere else?

Comment: Have you heard flux architecture??? Just search react flux and there you can get to know about "redux" or "alt flux" which will be perfect architecture of data flow and connect to external source.

Comment: I have heard of it. Is there perhaps a simpler answer. Smart people on the web, including Dan Abramov, a co-author of redux says it's a pain and "approach it with caution". I read this stuff before coming here.

Comment: I’ve used reflux before switching to to the redux. It is less complicated for start with than reflux, O guess. Because for server async request in redux the better approach is to use smth like redux-saga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to try some flux architecture. In this case it will looks similar to described below:

- You call action on delete button click, for example actions.deleteUser(1)
- Action calls appropriate API
- Store connected to your component changes and component state changes
- component re-rendered automatically

It depends on Flux that you prefer. The flow may be slightly different. I prefer reflux one

Answer (score 0):

In react, data flows only from parent component to child component. I assume that your state is stored in the parent component, since you have create, update and delete in separate components. The state can only be changed by calling the `setState()` function on it. Therefore child components cannot modify the state of the application. This can be done only by having a callback function.

The delete function will be written in the parent component and will be passed to delete component as a prop. The delete component will then call the delete function (callback) which will call the setState() upon the state of the parent component and thereby altering the state. Never alter the state of the application without setState().

Hope this helps

Comment: It may be passed as props of the parent component and may not be. It depends on particular component. CRUD action may be called from the component and due to the flux architecture component will be re-rendered.